# Webpack serving another url on file change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, nextcloud

I am working on a React project in order to build the user interface of a Nextcloud application. So far i used webpack to bundle all the code and use a single script file to inject in my Nextcloud application and it works.

The problem is the development experience, i would like to have features like auto-refresh of the page on file changes, so I am asking: **Is it possibile to serve with webpack-dev-server a static url as localhost:8080 where there are my containers running nextcloud and refresh it everytime webpack detect a change?**

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to Hot Module Replacement.
First, install Hot Module Replacement plugin, then configure your webpack as [this guide](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/)